# Possible to install Linux on computer that used to be Windows?

Tags: linux, operating-systems

I've got myself an extra computer that I would like to be a Linux setup.

Traditionally I am a Windows user, but I've been getting more and more exposure with Linux and really want to have a system solely dedicated to it.

The computer used to have Windows on it, all drives are removed, but can I install Linux on it or is the motherboards BIOS partial to Windows and thus I would need a new motherboard and processor?

I dont have much experience in the installing and uninstalling of varying OS's. I do have [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) as I have read Ubuntu is a good way to go for a Linux OS. Assuming it has a GUI as a native view rather than starting in terminal (correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

[That's all right? Should work, question answered ;-]

---

A little more elaboration seems required though...

Almost every pre-built computer comes with Windows, and almost every Linux wants to run, there's some UEFI fiddling and secure boot settings that may need to be played with, but most Linuces (Linuxes? Linuxii?) should run fine.

Especially with the drives removedthere should be little left of Windows anyway. Must have a new or empty drive now? Even with no (hard/internal) drive most Linux will run in RAM happily, I do it all the time (if you have enough ram, 4GB+ is great, 2GB is ok, 1GB or even 512MB should run enough to try).

The Q on AskUbuntu.com you linked looks very good, but sometimes (often) there's quirks with your particular computer, so do search for your computer / motherboard model and linux version to see if others have solved the same problems you may have

Comment: So the computer isnt pre-built. It was a custom build that I have since replaced. Windows 7 was the OS on the original drive; but if I put a new, blank drive in, I should be able to install a Linux OS from say a USB to that drive and the motherboard's BIOS wont care about the OS difference right?

Comment: Should be good. Getting the live USB created & the computer to boot from the USB may be the hardest parts, and Secure Boot may be a big hurdle, but once you've got a working  (bootable live Linux) USB give it a try - if something complains then search for things to try (like turn off Secure Boot, change settings, etc)

Comment: i mean to install directly from the usb to the drive; not boot always from the USB.

Comment: Same thing, have to boot usb then install from it, only changing the boot device again (if there wasn't a menu to pick a device, and normally boot from internal drive)

Comment: Okay, so at the root of this all, the motherboard is agnostic to what OS was previously being run?

Comment: @pstatix Yes. As said above the typical Linux installation is done on a machine on which Windows was pre-installed.